# Mobile Hamburger Menu 2 div's to close/open menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

Attempting to create a hamburger menu but using two separate div classes to open & close the menu using javascript. I'm unsure how i can achieve this, below is the HTML & CSS relevant.
What i would like to achieve is using `.Menu-Icon` to open the menu & `.Close` to close the menu.
The website is available here: https://blacklist-rs.com/design/

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thank you!
Please note, This isn't how the coding is formatted in the files. Snippets are of code that is relevant.

```css
.nav-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 340px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  transform: translate(-340px, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-340px, 0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-340px, 0);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}


/* Mobile CSS */

@media only screen and (max-width: 1276px) {
  .header .menu-icon {
    left: 75px;
    top: 46px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-image: url(../img/menu.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .header .logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 75px;
    transform: scale(0.5);
    margin-left: 0px;
    top: 15px;
  }
  .nav-2 {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 99999;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-2">
  <div class="main-menu">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#services">SERVICES</a></li>
      <li><a href="#projects">OUR PROJECTS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="menu-icon"></div>
<div class="logo"></div>
<div class="nav">
  <div class="nav-bg-close"></div>
  <div class="nav-container">
    <div class="close"></div>
    <div class="main-menu">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#services">Services</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in either a script tag, or link a js file with the defer attribute.

```
document.querySelector('.menu-icon').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('.nav-container').classList.toggle('nav-open')
})
```

It will toggle a class to the nav, write the styling that makes you nav open as the class called nav-open. Just make sure to write the styling for the open nav, below the styling for the closed nav. That will ensure that the closed styling gets overwritten.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I actually tried fiddling with the particular javascript code before you commented. 
Unfortunately your's and my code, did not toggle any class.
This may be due to my css, But unsure entirely.

Comment: If it does not toggle a class, either the querySelector gets the wrong items from the DOM, or your js doesn't run. If it gets the wrong items, you will see errors in the console. Else, you your code does not run. What does your console tell us?

Comment: Practical advide:
In you script, write: console.log('Script is running')
If you see the message in the console, you ran the script.
Then, make sure that the class names inside the selector is correct.

Comment: So the problem is solved? The problem is not the js (unless you changed the classes). The problem is that the script ran before the DOM is loaded, use the defer tag when linking the js file in the header.

<script defer src="filename.js"></script>

Comment: Apologies for the extended chat. Really appreciate your help, For some reason. You code has also managed to work after changing menu-icon to an id rather then a class.

This now works, But the nav-container is invisible due to the visibility hidden in the mobile query css. If i remove the visibility, the menu appears but as a static box. It automatically opens even when the event is not triggered. I'll update my website so you can view this. https://blacklist-rs.com/design/